# When to break a matrix into low rank and diagonal component?

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, matrix-rank

I want to decompose $Y \in \mathbb{R^{n \times n}}$ into low rank components such that $$Y = AB^T$$ where $A \in \mathbb{R^{n \times k}}$, $B \in \mathbb{R^{n \times k}}$ and $k < n$. $Y$ is a sparse matrix with non-zero diagonal elements, is it a good idea to decompose $Y$ into just low rank components or low rank components plus a diagonal term? If I don't include a diagonal term then the there is no meaning of decomposing into low rank components because $Y$ is full rank. Am I thinking in the right direction?

Comment: Why not use the economy SVD?

Comment: I am not sure if I should use $Y = AB^T$ this formulation or $Y = AB^T + D$ formulation where $D$ is a diagonal matrix. Is $Y$ a full rank matrix (because $Y$ is sparse and has non-zero diagonal elements)?

Comment: What is your overall goal? Which computation do you really care about? What can you say about the origin of the matrix $Y$ and the underlying application. We can not make any recommendation about your proposed scheme without this information.

Comment: Y is a sparse matrix with non-zero diagonal elements. I want to decompose it into sparse low-rank components. Now that I think of it, I found a solution. I should separate diagonal from the matrix and then decompose it into sparse low-rank components. If I don't remove non-zero diagonal elements from the matrix, then I can't decompose the matrix into low-rank components because $Y$ matrix is close to full rank.